# FilenotFoundException in Android using FileWriter

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, filewriter

I am new to java and android developement 
I am writting one xml file to my RSS feed 
Well my main probelm is that I am not able to execute statement as

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/webfeederiter.xml");
```

I am getting exception as FileNotFound, 
I cehck lots of option but nothing is working , my file is completly closed and I have all rights. One more I tried to put file in many location from \src , /assets but seems nothing is working

Any help ?
Thank in adavnce

Comment: Show us the complete error message

Comment: 02-13 16:15:01.396: W/System.err(616): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /assets/webfeedwriter.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 3):

> One more I tried to put file in many location from \src , /assets but
>   seems nothing is working

Both `src`,`assets`,`res` is not valid location for modifying files at runtime because all locations are  ***read-only at runtime***.

If you want to write to file at runtime then move it on Internal/External Storage of device. then use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` for getting File from storage:

```
String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
File file=new File(baseDir+"/webfeederiter.xml");
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
...
```